# strtok and escape characters

Tags: c, shell, escaping, strtok

I'm working on a shell in C that uses strtok on the space char (' ') to create a list of arguments from the user input. For example, strtok 'ls foo bar' creates a char* with three elements: ls, foo, bar.

My question is, how do I detect escape-space?

For example, strtok 'ls foo\ bar' creates a char** with three elements: ls, foo\, bar. But it should create a char* with two elements: ls, foo bar

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to use `strtok`, since `strtok` doesn't understand escape characters. You can try to hack around this, but ultimately if you want to support things like quoted arguments, you will want to have a more flexible approach.

Consider writing a parser instead. Just loop over every character in the input and decide what to do with that character: spaces advance to the next argument, backslashes copy the next character verbatim, quotes start a quoted context, etc. It's a much more flexible way to handle input, and you won't be constrained by the limits of `strtok`.

Comment: Thanks, I will start a parser function

Answer (score 0):

Just change the second argument to strtok from `" "` to `" \"` (the "delimiters").  These are the characters that will determine where the user input gets split into tokens, and as a result none of them will make it into the list of tokens.  See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) for more information about strtok.

Edit: sorry, I misunderstood you.  The above advice would just remove `\`s.  I agree that parsing manually is the way to go.  It's easiest to get characters one at a time, using `fgetc()`, say.